# How do I filter a string through multiple arrays and choose the one with the most resemblance

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, artificial-intelligence

**I'm not asking for a code-example, just asking for the best way possible**

So I'm currently creating a robot-answered helpdesk which answers with specific answers (like the contact-address) when it recognizes specific words (like if a user enters 'stuur mail' it will say 'Als je een mailtje wil sturen kan dit naar help@wordquest.nl')

It works with arrays, so there's an array

> mailText['stuur', 'mail', 'verzend'];

And there's a function (*checkMail()*) that checks how much of the given text (*from a input field*) is in the array. So if a user enters 'hoe stuur ik een mail' it recognizes 'stuur' and 'mail' and knows that 66% percent of the words from the mailText array are used. I currently have two arrays like this. And it works, with 4 if-statements to check which one fits the users input best, but I really don't want to write hundreds of if-statements comparing arrays and creating a function for every array.

The current JS is

```
window.onkeydown = function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        checkQuestions(document.getElementsByClassName('inputField')[0].value);

        document.getElementsByClassName('inputField')[0].value = '';

        if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault(); // This should fix it
            return false; // Just a workaround for old browsers
    }
}

var mail = ['stuur', 'mail', 'verzend'];
var verzenden = ['kost', 'verzend', 'pakket'];

var errorText = '<h1>An error has occured...</h1><br>There are no answers with the current search query...';

var mailText = 'Als je een mailtje wil sturen kan dit naar <a 
href="mailto:help@wordquest.nl">help@wordquest.nl</a>';
var sendText = 'Verzendkosten verschillen per pakket';

var answers = [];

function checkQuestions(quest) {
    console.log('');
    answer = 0;
    finalText = errorText;
    answers = [];

    mailNum = checkMail(quest);
    sendNum = checkSend(quest);

    if (mailNum > sendNum) {
        answers.push(mailText);
    } else if (sendNum > mailNum) {
        answers.push(sendText);
    } else if (sendNum == mailNum && sendNum != 0) {
        answers.push(mailText);
        answers.push(sendText);
    } else {
        answers.push(errorText);
    }

    setAnswer();
}

function checkMail(question) {
    chance = 0;
    indent = 100 / mail.length;
    for (i = 0; i < mail.length; i++) {
        if (question.includes(mail[i])) {
            chance = chance + indent;
        }
    }
    console.log('mail is ' + chance + '%');
    return chance;
}

function checkSend(question) {
    chance = 0;
    indent = 100 / verzenden.length;
    for (i = 0; i < verzenden.length; i++) {
        if (question.includes(verzenden[i])) {
            chance = chance + indent;
        }
    }
    console.log('verzenden is ' + chance + '%');
    return chance;
}

var finalAns = [];

function setAnswer() {
    finalAns = [];

    if (answers[0] != errorText) {
        finalAns.push('<b>Er zijn ' + answers.length + ' antwoorden gevonden!</b>');
    }

    for (i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
        finalAns.push('<p>' + answers[i] + '</p>');
    }

    document.getElementsByClassName('answers')[0].innerHTML = finalAns.join('');
}
```

Current page (with HTML): https://codepen.io/timyboy12345/pen/YEpmZz

**I know this is probably not the best way to do this, but it's just a hobby-project...**

So does anyone have a good idea on how to make a function that compares the users input to all array's with answer-combinations (+50 in the end probably) without creating a function for every array, and give the user a correct text (I'm using predefined variables at the moment) with the answer to their question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use nested arrays and use a counter to track the number of words matched. Then you calculate the percentage of accuracy and use a final array to know which array was correctly answered.

Pseudo-code for the loops:

```
for i = 0; i < arraysToMatch; i++
    nbMatched = 0
    foreach answer in answerArray[i]
        if answer is in arraysToMatch[i] then
            ++nbMatched
        end if
    end foreach

    // Here calculate the accuracy and if good use i       

end for
```

That way you don't need a function for each arrays. However, you will need to pair the matching array with the answer array.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I found the solution in a nested arrays:

The final version uses an array with nested arrays (with the name antwoordenMogelijk). So antwoordenMogelijk[0] contains all the possible queries for option 1, antwoordenMogelijk[1] contains the queries for option 2 and so forth.

```
window.onkeydown = function (event) {
if (event.keyCode == 13) {
       // console.log("test");
       checkQuestions(document.getElementsByClassName('inputField')[0].value);

       document.getElementsByClassName('inputField')[0].value = '';

       if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
       return false;
   }
}

var mail = new Array();
var verzenden = new Array();

var antwoordenMogelijk = new Array();
var antwoorden = new Array();
var perc = new Array();

//0 Mail
//1 Verzenden

antwoordenMogelijk[0] = new Array('stuur', 'mail', 'verzend', 'help', 'vraag');
antwoorden[0] = 'Als je een mailtje wil sturen kan dit naar <a href="mailto:help@wordquest.nl">help@wordquest.nl</a>.';

antwoordenMogelijk[1] = ['log', 'inloggen', 'in'];
antwoorden[1] = 'Inloggen gaat via <a href="http://wordquest.nl/login">registreren</a>.';

antwoordenMogelijk[2] = ['nieuw', 'account', 'aanmaken', 'registreer', 'maak'];
antwoorden[2] = 'Nieuwe accounts kan je aanmaken via <a href="http://wordquest.nl/registreer">registreren</a>.';

antwoordenMogelijk[3] = ['suggestie', 'sturen', 'contact'];
antwoorden[3] = 'Suggesties kan je sturen via <a href="mailto:help@wordquest.nl">deze link</a>.';

antwoordenMogelijk[4] = ['veranderen', 'character', 'avatar'];
antwoorden[4] = 'Je character kan je makkelijk veranderen op <a    href="http://wordquest.nl/avatar">deze pagina</a>';

var errorText = '<b>An error has occured...</b><br>Er zijn geen antwoorden gevonden met de huidige zoekterm(en)...';

var answers = [];
var final = [];
var finalP;

function checkQuestions(quest) {
    console.log('');
    answer = 0;
    finalP = 0;
    final = [];
    answers = [];

    checkAnswer(quest);

    for (i = 0; i < perc.length; i++) {
        if (perc[i] > 5) {
            if (perc[i] == finalP) {
                finalP = perc[i];
                final.push(antwoorden[i]);
            } else if (perc[i] > finalP) {
                finalP = perc[i];
                final = [];
                final.push(antwoorden[i]);
            }
        }
    }

   if (final[0] == null) {
       final.push(errorText);
   }

   setAnswer();
 }

 var amount = 0;

 function checkAnswer(question) {
    for (i = 0; i < antwoordenMogelijk.length; i++) {
        perc[i] = 0;
        for (x = 0; x < antwoordenMogelijk[i].length; x++) {
            amount = 100 / antwoordenMogelijk[i].length;
            if (question.includes(antwoordenMogelijk[i][x])) {
                perc[i] = perc[i] + amount;
                console.log('Antwoord: ' + antwoordenMogelijk[i][x] + ' - +' + amount);   
            }
        }
        if (perc[i] > 0) {
            console.log('Uiteindelijk: ' + perc[i]);
        }
    }
}

var finalAns = [];

function setAnswer() {

    finalAns = [];

    for (i = 0; i < final.length; i++) {
        finalAns.push('<p>' + final[i] + '</p>');
   }

    if (final != 'error') {
        document.getElementsByClassName('answers')[0].innerHTML =    finalAns.join('');
        // document.getElementsByClassName('answers')[0].innerHTML = '<p>' + antwoorden[final] + '</p>';
    } else {
        document.getElementsByClassName('answers')[0].innerHTML = '<p>' + errorText + '</p>';
    }
}

function start() {
    console.log("Gestart");
    // answers.push('Voorbeelden van vragen zijn:<br><ul><li>Hoe stuur ik een mailtje</li><li>Wat kost een pakketje verzenden</li></ul>');
   }
```